# vanilla JS login functionality for websites

Tags: javascript, authentication, login-control

I have been researching a problem: using vanilla JS to implement the login functionality of a website like so http://jsbin.com/jodiwo/1/edit?html,css,output, I have not had much success. I know it is a no-no using JS to do this as the password could be read of the View Source page. Any pointers as to how I may implement this without using nodeJS (or other fancy library) based approach?

Thanks tons!

Comment: Um, if you want to do usernames and passwords, you need a serverside language of some sort. It can not be done solely on the clientside.

Comment: You cannot make a secure login without using server-based code somewhere.  Only a server can be trusted to actually evaluate a password and control access.  Client code can always be bypassed.

Comment: This question as a serious DON'T DO THIS sign above it.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback, is there some way to use vanilla JS straight up on the serverside...? (*scratchingHead)

Comment: You can do this through [NodeJS](http://passportjs.org/), which is just javascript.